# Error installing Ubuntu using Wubi

Tags: wubi

I am new to the community and would love to try out Ubuntu. I chose to install it using Wubi to save the pain of reformatting etc.

I have now tried the installer several times using different partitions but I get an error. Here is part of the log file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 132, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in run_installer
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 463, in expand_diskimage
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\utils.py", line 66, in run_command
Exception: Error executing command
>>command=C:\DOCUME~1\ARISH'~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl336.tmp\bin\resize2fs.exe -f C:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk 17744M
>>retval=1
>>stderr=
>>stdout=resize2fs 1.40.6 (09-Feb-2008)
Usage: /cygdrive/c/DOCUME~1/ARISH~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/pyl336.tmp/bin/resize2fs.exe -f C:/ubuntu/disks/root.disk 17744M [-d debug_flags] [-f] [-F] [-p] device [new_size]
```

Comment: Why don't you pastebin the entire log file so we can see the release and other important information? Based solely on the lines you provided I'd guess that there was only a partial download of the diskimage file, but it's impossible to say based on those few lines.

Comment: I hope its allowed on the community
http://rapidshare.com/files/1784953147/wubi-12.04-rev272.log

Answer (score 0):

The download of the diskimage looks like it completed okay, so there's a possibility it's corrupted. Instead you can download the `ISO` directly ([releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-i386.iso](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-i386.iso)) or using the torrent ([releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-i386.iso.torrent](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-i386.iso.torrent)), which is better since your internet connection is intermittent.

Save the `ISO` in the same folder as `wubi.exe` before running, and it will use the `ISO` instead of the diskimage.